# Which hosting model for Blazor application with dynamic UI talking to remote SQL Server?

Tags: signalr, webassembly, blazor, asp.net-core-signalr, blazor-server-side

If you wanted to port a "legacy" ASP.NET application that fetches data from a remote SQL Server instance by way of `System.Data.SqlCient` methods running in the code-behind of a `HttpHandler` (the data returned from the server gets jsonified and injected into the UI widgets, e.g. kendoUI), what is the appropriate Blazor hosting model?

```
  Blazor server-side  
  Blazor ASP.NET Core Hosted 
  Blazor client-side
```

Judging from the description that Visual Studio 2019 Preview offers of `Blazor (server-side)`:

> ... This template can be used for web applications with rich dynamic user interfaces...

`Blazor (server-side)` seems the right choice.

But does `SignalR` give you a way to use `Blazor (ASP.NET Core hosted)` instead? Visual Studio says this hosting model "runs on WebAssembly and is hosted on an ASP.NET Core server" but I'm not sure what that means, exactly. Where is the WebAssembly running? Client? Server? Both places?

Can `SignalR` together with the `Blazor (ASP.NET Core hosted)` model be used to create a pipeline from the server-side `WebAssembly` to the client-side `WebAssembly` that obviates the need for the `HttpHandler`?

The description of SignalR here on StackOverflow suggests that it is almost magical in its capabilities:

> ASP.NET SignalR ... makes it *incredibly simple* to add real-time web functionality to your applications...to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as it happens, in real-time.
>   [my emphasis]

Ignoring the "as it happens, in real-time" phrase for a moment as being unrelated to the question, can the same pipeline be used to push any (smallish) data-set to the "connected client"?  This is a legacy "intranet" application that I'm asking about, BTW, with only a few dozen users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> that fetches data from a remote SQL Server instance by way of System.Data.SqlCient

That part should defintely run on the server. There is no SqlClient in the Browser.
Running Blazor server-side ought to work. You should not have to deal with SignalR directly.

> running in the code-behind of a HttpHandler (the data returned from the server gets jsonified and ...

That sounds like it would fit to the Hosted model: an API server exposing endpoints to the client. It would leave you with the best architecture, but it may be more work.

Comment: SqlClient technology is used to retrieve data from an SQL Server database. It is not supported on client devices such as a web browser. It is supported on the server. Your conclusion, however,  that Blazor server-side should be selected on account of this is incorrect. In both mode of execution, server-side or client side Blazor, SqlClient technology is employed on the server, be it a Web Api controller class, or a local simple service...

Comment: @Isaac: I am confused by your remark to Henk. The Core Hosted model splits the project into app.Client and app.Server parts. Why wouldn't System.Data.SqlClient be accessible in one of the app.Server.Controllers?

Comment: @Issac - I never drew the conclusion that "that Blazor server-side should be selected". Your reading is incorrect.

Comment: @Tim - you are right. Your choices are the Hosted model (Blazor CS + Web API) or Blazor ServerSide. I would favour the Hosted model for now, a Web API is very established. Using a Db in Server side still has its problems (like lack of usable Scoping).

Comment: @Tim, where exactly have I said that  System.Data.SqlClient wouldn't be "accessible in one of the app.Server.Controllers?" I've explicitly said "In both mode of execution, server-side or client side Blazor, SqlClient technology is employed on the server, be it a Web Api controller class, or a local simple service.." Please, read my comment again and again till you fully comprehend it. Then read my answer once more, so that you really understand what I am saying. I know it's not easy to understand,  not the language but the concepts behind it, but this is the way to understand what is Blazor.

Comment: "@Tim - you are right" Right about what ? Do you mind elaborating?

Comment: @Henk Holterman, your answer is contains two quotes, each of which is accompanied by a suggestion. I've already related to the first quote, now I shall relate to the second one:  HttpHandler, in its simplest sense is a class (process) that handles incoming requests made to the ASP.NET websites. Web Service Handler (.asmx) is a good example. Indeed, "API server exposing endpoints to the client", or Web Api controller class, is the replacement of the old Asp.Net HTTPHandlers in Asp.Net Core. But how can you conclude from this that Hosted model should be chosen!

Comment: Continue.....This factor, however, has no weight whatsoever, in determining what mode of execution to choose. Can't I use Web Api with Server-Side Blazor ! Of course I can. Can't I use a local simple server in a Server-Side Blazor, to access data  and send it to the calling code !  Of course I can... Blazor  you...

Answer (score 2):

Way too many question for a single 'Question"

Question: But does SignalR give you a way to use Blazor (ASP.NET Core hosted) instead?

Answer: In other words, you're question is whether SingleR can be used from client-side Blazor, right ? The answer is yes...

Question: Visual Studio says this hosting model "runs on WebAssembly and is hosted on an ASP.NET Core server" but I'm not sure what that means, exactly. Where is the WebAssembly running? Client? Server? Both places?

Answer: Client-side Blazor is executed on the client browser. Blazor client-side is executed by the mono run time that is compiled to WebAssembly. WebAssembly cannot run on the server.It is designed to run on the web, alongside JavaScript. Blazor client-side is hosted on the server, and it is an Asp.Net Core project.

Question: Can SignalR together with the Blazor (ASP.NET Core hosted) model be used to create a pipeline from the server-side WebAssembly to the client-side WebAssembly that obviates the need for the HttpHandler?

Answer: No such animal server-side WebAssembly. You can use Web Api to enable communication between your Blazor client-side and the server. In that case, you'll have to use the HttpClient service. 
Note: you may also use SignleR for such communication of real-time is essential.

What is HttpHandler ? A web Api controller is an HttpHandler... an action (a routing endpoint) in such a controller is an HttpHandler... Names are not important. The question is what problem do you want to solve.

Seems to me that you'd better create your app with Server-side Blazor, in which case you may use the HttpClient Service, or perhaps not use HttpClient at all, and instead define a service which push the data to the browser, as after all, your code is executed on the server, and data is pushed to the browser via SignleR.

**UPDATE**:

Question: @Isaac: Thanks for tackling the question(s) :) My underlying question is whether, in a Blazor web application, server-side code is (somehow) able to update UI components directly, perhaps via some RPC mechanism over SignalR, which would eliminate the need to expose a routing endpoint to the client and eliminate Ajax. I thought WASM could run server-side too. I am thinking of intranet apps, not internet apps, in terms of number of clients (relatively few).

Answer: Conjure up a page in a Browser with an input[type=text] and a button control "Click me". Again, this page is running in the browser. It might be a client-side Blazor, but it might also be server-side Blazor. I know the secret, and I'm going to tell it to you. Our dear app is a **Blazor server-side**. Now enter a value to the input box and hit the "Click me" button. Right after you've clicked the button, SignleR pass the data you entered as well as every details such as the event type, etc. In short, the event is executed on the server. No Ajax, on your part... How SignleR works is of minor importance here. What is essential to understand that your code is executed on the server, not on the client, as happens when you use Client-side Blazor (WebAssembly).

As I've already said above, the your code is executed on the server, and thus you don't have to expose routing endpoints to the client. You can simply define a service in your app, inject it to the DI container, and use it to call methods on it that do something interesting...

**NEW UPDATE:**

Question: Thanks. What if the user's button-click sends the text in a text box to the server, which does a database query using the text-value as a search-term, and then the server needs to send a dataset back to the client to populate a grid? Does the server invoke (remotely) a client-side method and supply the data as an argument to the client-side method?

It is not clear from your question which mode of execution you are relating to. However, the flow of execution depicted here may be relevant to both client-side Blazor, and server-side Blazor.

When the user hit the button, an event handler defined on the client app and running on the browser (Note that this can be either client-side Blazor or server-side Blazor), is triggered. This handler may use an injected HttpClient to send the content of the textbox, and wait for a response, if you're lucky, containing your searched data. I guess you know how to use the HttpClient object, right ? You post a request and then you gets a response. The retrieved data may be assigned to a local variable, and bound to, say, a table element which can display the data in a grid.

I hope that you do understand that the http request is posted to a controller class defined on the server; that is you use Web Api.

This flow of events is, again, identical in both client-side and server-side mode of execution.

But, as your app is executed on the server, when you use server-side Blazor, you don't have to use Web Api, and can define a service instead which returns the required data. Note that the asking for data, querying the database, returning the data, executing code, rendering html, etc. all occurs on the server, at the end of which a SignleR method push the HTML diffs to the client Browser for display.

Hope this helps...

Comment: @Isaac: Thanks for tackling the question(s) :)   My underlying question is whether, in a Blazor web application, server-side code is (somehow) able to update UI components directly, perhaps via some RPC mechanism over SignalR, which would eliminate the need to expose a routing endpoint to the client and eliminate Ajax.  I thought WASM could run server-side too. I am thinking of intranet apps, not internet apps, in terms of number of clients (relatively few).

Comment: Thanks. What if the user's button-click sends the text in a text box to the server, which does a database query using the text-value as a search-term, and then the server needs to send a dataset back to the client to populate a grid? Does the server invoke (remotely) a client-side method and supply the data as an argument to the client-side method?

Comment: Are you Asp.Net Web Forms developer, @Tim ?

Comment: @Isaac:  I am a jack of all trades and master of none :)  Oracle (PL/SQL), SQLServer (T-SQL), postGRES (PL/SQL), SQLite, WinForms, C#, VB, HTML5, javascript, jQuery, ajax, kendoUI, knockout (not to mention PICK database in a former life).  Now I would like to learn Blazor but cannot find a clear description (clear to me, at least) of the differences between HTML5 with Ajax and Blazor, in respect to how the two architectures avoid refreshing the entire page when the user interacts with it.  I believed that SignalR may eliminate the need to use Ajax for that effect, but am not certain of that

Answer (score 0):

I have setup a client side Blazor application that uses a MySQL database. The way I have done it is using a PHP based REST API for all the transactions between the database and the Blazor app. I also added some login security to it as well done in the PHP and storing some tokens in the MySQL database for each login that then times out after a while with no new calls from that login using that token or that login.

So far I am very happy with this solution as it gives a lot of freedom regarding the server and what can be done with the application. The main downside is that it can require quite a bit from the client depending on how heavy the application is. But the server requirement is very low though as pretty much anything can run a PHP / MySQL server.

ASP should be pretty close to PHP, so a similar solution should be possible using ASP.